# How to alter the string format of the text between the line number and the history entry in the output of history in bash?

Tags: bash, history

How to alter the string format of the text between the line number and the history entry in the output of history in bash?

If running `history` in bash prints, for example:

```
5  history
```

how to change that to this, for instance:

```
5....history
```

or

```
5_anyString_history
```

Also, alignment is done by `history` already, by adjusting the number of spaces. How to include this functionality as well? That is, if . is used as the string, how to change the number of dots according to the number of digits in the line number? Also, I'd like to remove the leading spaces.

Comment: Do you want BASH to able to process your changes history file again or just have an out formatted the way you described?

Comment: I'm only looking to change the output so it's easier to view for me, so I'm not looking to change any of the internal processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
history | sed 's/^\( *[0-9]*\) */\1../'
```

When I do `history`, there is always two spaces after the line number. The alignment is done by varying the number of spaces *before* the number.

This is an example of how to replace the *leading* spaces (which vary in number):

```
history | sed 's/^ */&\n/; :a; s/ \(.*\n\)/.\1/; ta; s/\n//'
```

**Edit:**

This version works similarly to the second one above, but it moves the dots after the numbers so there are no leading spaces and the variable number of dots cause the history entries to be left aligned.

```
sed 's/^ */&\n/; :a; s/ \(.*\n\)/.\1/; ta; s/\n//;s/\(\.*\)\([^ ]*\) */\2\1/'
1....aaa bbb ccc
22...ddd eee fff
333..ghi jkl mno
```

This is how it works:

- add a newline after the initial sequence of spaces (divide and conquer)
- `:a` - label for branching
- replace one space before the newline with a dot
- `ta` - branch to label `:a` if a replacement is made, once all the leading spaces are replaced, continue past the branch instruction
- remove the newline
- capture the dots and non-spaces (digits) in two capture groups and exclude the spaces after the numbers
- and swap the two groups (so the dots now come after the numbers)

Comment: While your answer is very helpful and clear, it would help me if you commented the sed commands to indicate what they do, so it's easier for me to adapt them (especially the branching in the second).  Btw, I'd like to remove the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
type history 
history is a shell builtin
```

tells us, that the history is a builtin, so you would need to take the source of bash, and modify it.